# logging from symfony unit test?

Tags: logging, symfony1

I have an empty unit test in symfony... I want to log ANYTHING to the console or a log file.. How can I make this happen? it seems like any echoing I do or any intentional exceptions I throw are eaten when I run "symfony test:all" even though I can see the test is in fact being run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things get way easier if you run the individual test...

"symphony test:unit testName"

suddenly I am seeing output.